# HTML CSS Vertical spacing between <a> elements of same DIV

Tags: html, css, image, margin

At the moment, what I have is seen in the first picture. I would like to know how can I add the spaces (bottom margin?) between the images as shown in picture 2? They 2 side-by-side blocks are 2 different DIVs, and the pictures in each line are  elements of the same div, so bottom-margin doesn't work. (CODE AT THE BOTTOM)

Picture 1:

[image]

Picture 2:

[image]

HTML:

```
...
<div class="meniu">
                    <a href="#">NAUJIENOS</a>
                    <a href="#">KREPSINIO VADOVAS</a>
                    <a href="#">TRENIRUOTES</a>
                    <a href="#">IDOMYBES</a>
                    <a href="#">GALERIJA</a>
                    <a href="#">APIE MUS</a>
                </div>
                <div class="rightbar">
                    <div class="rightpic2"> 
                        <a href="#"><img src="pic3.png"></a> <br>
                        <a href="#"><img src="pic4.png"></a> <br>
                        <a href="#"><img src="pic4.png"></a> <br>
                        <a href="#"><img src="pic5.png"></a> <br>
                        <a href="#"><img src="pic3.png"></a> 
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="rightpic1"> 
                    <a href="#"><img src="pic1.jpg"></a> <br>
                    <a href="#"><img src="pic2.jpg"></a>

                </div>
...
```

CSS:

```
.rightpic1{
        float:right;
        margin-right:30px;
        margin-top:100px;


    }

    .rightpic2{

        margin-right:24px;
        margin-left:24px;
        margin-top:38px;
    }

    .rightbar{

        float:right;
        background-color:white;
        margin-top:62px;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<a>` elements display inline. Nix all the `<br>` in the markup and add `display: block` to the css.

```
.rightpic1 a, .rightpic2 a {
    display: block;
    margin-top: 15px
}
```

Comment: Thank You, however I used margin-bottom to get the correct margins :) It still worked out though!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to close all your image tags. Then add `display:block;` to the links inside your `.rightpick1` & `.rightpick2` classes. Then, you can successfully add a `margin-bottom` to your links.

I attached a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dBzKd/) as an example. Hope that helps!